# How to find three most entered value in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following set of datas:

```
df['Coefficient'] = [0.1,0.2,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.6,0.9,0.8,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.8,0.4,0.1,0.2,0.5,0.9,0.7,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.2,0.8,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.1,0.3,0.9,0.8,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.5]
```

How to find the the three most entered coefficient values using python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with selecting first `3` index values, because `value_counts` sorts output:

```
print (df['Coefficient'].value_counts())
0.2    9
0.5    9
0.3    4
0.1    4
0.8    4
0.6    3
0.9    3
0.4    2
0.7    1
Name: Coefficient, dtype: int64

print (df['Coefficient'].value_counts().index[:3])
Float64Index([0.2, 0.5, 0.3], dtype='float64')
```

Comment: Glad can help you. Good luck and nice day and weekend!

Answer (score 1):

The solutions proposed by @jezrael and @Saikat are concise and elegant.

Here's another solution using a `defaultdict:`

```
from collections import defaultdict

df = dict()
df['Coefficient'] = [0.1,0.2,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.6,0.9,0.8,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.8,0.4,0.1,0.2,0.5,0.9,0.7,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.2,0.8,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.1,0.3,0.9,0.8,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.5]

d = defaultdict(int)

for i in df['Coefficient']:
    d[i] += 1

for w in sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True):
      print(w, d[w])
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(pd.Series(df['Coefficient']).value_counts())`

As for me the other answer was throwing error.
Another similar question :[How to find three most entered value in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43536026/how-to-find-three-most-entered-value-in-a-column)

Comment: Hmmm, my setup is `df = pd.DataFrame()`
`df['Coefficient'] = [0.1,0.2,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.6,0.9,0.8,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.8,0.4,0.1,0.2,0.5,0.9,0.7,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.2,0.8,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.1,0.3,0.9,0.8,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.5]`
`print (df)`

Answer (score 0):

```html
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Coefficient': [0.1,0.2,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.6,0.9,0.8,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.8,0.4,0.1,0.2, \
                                    0.5,0.9,0.7,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.2,0.8,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.1,0.3,0.9, \
                                    0.8,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.5]})
# Count the occurences of values
print (df['Coefficient'].value_counts())
0.2    9
0.5    9
0.3    4
0.1    4
0.8    4
0.6    3
0.9    3
0.4    2
0.7    1
Name: Coefficient, dtype: int64

# Retain the top 3 most common
print (df['Coefficient'].value_counts().iloc[:3])
0.2    9
0.5    9
0.3    4
Name: Coefficient, dtype: int64

# Only the values of the three most common in an array
print (df['Coefficient'].value_counts().iloc[:3].index.values)
[ 0.2  0.5  0.3]
```